# Android - ARCore : How can I distinguish detected planes?

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

I have been exploring ARCore SDK along with sceneform.

Question 1: Is it possible to distinguish detected planes using ARCore, Sceneform and Android studio (to be specific).

Question 2: I am curious to know after reading discussion on github link: https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/issues/117
as "haris-tankovic" has asked " Is it possible to expand detected plane to infinity? If so, how can I do it?", so is it possible?